# VBCodeProvider Can not cast correctly the Implicit Variable declaration on compile

Tags: vb.net, compilation, codedom, vbcodeprovider

I am Compiling My string Code(I read My Code from Text File) In vb and it works fine but i have a function that returns nullable double(Double?)

when i use it like this

```
Dim x As Double? = Myfunc(1000) 'it returns Nothing
```

my x variable fills with Nothing and it's ok

But When I use it like this

```
Dim x = Myfunc(1000) 'it returns Nothing
```

my x value is 0 !!!!

How can i solve this problem 
i want my users write codes like first code block

i tested all Option Explicit and Option Strict but it did not gain me anything.

please let me know how can i use Just dim x not Dim x as (type)
thank you for your helps

**UPDATE** :this is Myfunc Code :

```
   Function Myfunc(parameterId As Long) As Double?

        If parameterId = 1000 Then
               Return Nothing
        Else
            Return tot(parameterId) 'it is a dictionary of values
        End If

    End Function
```

And this Is my Compile Class :

```
     Private Shared Function Compile(ByVal vbCode As String) As CompilerResults
        Dim providerOptions = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0")

        ' Create the VB.NET compiler.
        Dim vbProv = New VBCodeProvider(providerOptions)
        ' Create parameters to pass to the compiler.
        Dim vbParams = New CompilerParameters()
        ' Add referenced assemblies.



        vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll")
        vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll")
        vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
        vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
        vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll")
        vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")
        vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll")
        vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll")


        vbParams.GenerateExecutable = False
        ' Ensure we generate an assembly in memory and not as a physical file.
        vbParams.GenerateInMemory = True

        ' Compile the code and get the compiler results (contains errors, etc.)
        Return vbProv.CompileAssemblyFromSource(vbParams, vbCode)

    End Function
```

Comment: by "Compile My string Code" do you mean CodeDOM?  what does `myfunc` look like?

Comment: Let Me update My quesion

Comment: it's Update If you need something else just tell me :)

Comment: your code is doing exactly what you told it to do.  What do you want it to return?

Comment: when i use Dim x = Myfunc(1000) it returns 0 not Nothing

Comment: You have Myfun and Myfunc?

Comment: I don't think you can declare a variable with a nullable type implicitly in .net?

Comment: I have `Option Explicit`, `Strict` and `Infer` all set to `On`.
When I run the OP's code I get `Nothing` in both cases.
How are you getting it to return a 0?

Comment: you can do it in vb .... my codes works fine with vb run-time Compiler but when i compile this with VBCodeProvider it can not cast corectlly

Comment: @ Mr CoDeXeR sorry My type mistake

Comment: @Grim did you compile it with System.CodeDom.Compiler? or you just run it?

Comment: @Grim Your are awesome man!!! it was Option Infer On.... i did not know anything about it .... write your comment in answers Please.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised you edited your first post.  Should've refreshed the page.  I was running in VS.
Stands to reason that if the VS compiler produces a different result to your compiler, then you need to check the parameters and settings you're using.

Comment: @Grim i did check option Explicit and Strict But i did not know about Infer.

Comment: No offence, but if you're dropping `As <Type>` statements out of your code, you should know why!

Comment: actually im C# developer and vb is getting me crazy with this games :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed above, `Option Infer On` needs to be included to force the compiler to create the variable as the required type - in this case the `Double?` returned by `MyFunc`.